# Drawing an arrow pointing at the "Enable Dynamics" button

Tags: dynamic, notebooks

Sometimes my students are given Mathematica notebooks as part of an assignment, and asked to go through some demonstrations contained in the .nb file.  A lot of times I get complaints that the "graphs aren't showing up" or "all I see is lines of code".  The problem usually is that they haven't enabled dynamics on that particular notebook.

What I'd like to do is have an arrow contained in the notebook that points directly at the "Enable Dynamics" button which shows when a notebook is opened. Then, once the button is clicked, *the arrow disappears*.

I know how to draw an arrow, but what I don't know how to do is:

1. Have that arrow point to the corner of the notebook window, where the button is;
2. have that arrow disappear once the button is clicked.

Any help or pointers on this would be sincerely appreciated!

Comment: `FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["ToggleDynamicUpdating"]]` will _toggle_ the setting (but it isn't an on-off thing!)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would approach this problem a bit differently. I would provide each such notebook with an initialization button at its top, right under its title, if any. By pressing this button, the dynamic apdating would be enabled.  How to do it technically, is already in the comment of belisarius. The further is only a question of a design. The latter should be catching attention, so that even a lazy student would immediately notice it. That depends, of course, of a personal taste of yours. I would propose the following:

```
    Button[Style["Initialize: press me before you start", Red, Bold], 
 FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["ToggleDynamicUpdating"]], 
 ImageSize -> {350, 20}]
```

When you prepare the notebook, evaluate once this code. The button will appear in the output cell. I propose to select then the cell bracket and to click Menu/Format/Text Alignment/Align Center. The button will be centered. You then can collapse the input cell (go to Menu/Cell/Cell Properties and uncheck "Open"). The notebook will look like this:[image]
As one reasonable extension, you might want to include evaluation of initialization cells into the same button:

```
    Button[Style["Initialize: press me before you start", Red, 
  Bold], (FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["ToggleDynamicUpdating"]];
  FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["EvaluateInitialization"]]), 
 ImageSize -> {350, 20}]
```

Have fun.

Comment: Wouldn't the usual Mathematica button still display when this notebook is opened?

Comment: Does including the `EvaluateInitialization` action really provide any functionality that cannot already be obtained by suitably setting the notebook's options? (That is, `NotebookOptions` > `Evaluation Options` > `InitializationCellEvaluation` : `True`)

Comment: @murray In principle it does not. I did not know about the possibility you write about and tried it just now. In my case the InitializationCellEvaluation are preset to Automatic and are blended out. No access to it therefore. I would prefer this way, if accessible. Have you an idea, how to make it active? HMy proposal to include evaluation of initialization cells into the button has the background that there is anyway a button to enable dynamics. So, why not to include there everything.

Comment: @Steve D Yes, you are right. The button is already there. Your problem is (as much as I understand it) that the students are too lazy or, may be, not curious enough to notice the button at the margins and to press it. So it is more a psychological question, then a programmatic one. My idea is that as soon as there is such a button inside the notebook, as I propose: a rather large and bright, carrying a text demanding to press it in the beginning of their work, the students will more easily notice it and understand that they should press it.

Comment: @murray I realized that this should be fixed Globally, rather than for the selected document. It is a great possibility, but with one draw back. Fixing such an option globally prohibits to export documents into cdf. Otherwise it is, indeed, an excellent solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

According to my rough test, the `DynamicUpdating` option used at the Notebook level can override the global setting. To demonstrate that, here is a simple test.

1. Start a fresh new *Mathematica*, and goto **Evaluation** menu, uncheck the **Dynamic Updating Enabled** term.

   Or goto the **Option Inspector**, select **Global Preference**, then set **Cell Options** -> **Evaluation Options** -> **"DynamicUpdating"** to **False**.

   [image: option inspector]

   **Note:** According to [Jacob Akkerboom](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38692/drawing-an-arrow-pointing-at-the-enable-dynamics-button/38719?noredirect=1#comment116127_38719), this is equivalent to `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, DynamicUpdating -> False]`. Also note it overrides the **Dynamic Updating Enabled** menu setting.
2. Using any text editor to create the following two Notebook files:

   [image: notebook comparison]

   ```
   Notebook[{Cell[BoxData[DynamicBox[ToBoxes[Date[],StandardForm],UpdateInterval:>0]],"Output"]}]
   ```

   ---

   ```
   Notebook[{Cell[BoxData[DynamicBox[ToBoxes[Date[],StandardForm],UpdateInterval:>0]],"Output"]},DynamicUpdating->True]
   ```
3. Open them in *Mathematica*, we can see despite the dynamic-updating being globally disabled, the later Notebook still functions.

   [image: comparison in mma]

### Notebook Security

About [Kuba's comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38692/drawing-an-arrow-pointing-at-the-enable-dynamics-button/38719?noredirect=1#comment115919_38719) on the safety issue, I think it won't be a problem, as when the nb file is NOT on a "TrustedPath", *Mathematica* will always detect [*unsafe dynamic content*](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NotebookSecurity.html) and raise an alarm if there is any, even the global dynamic-updating is set to **True**.

Here is a simple test.

1. Set `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, DynamicUpdating -> True]`.
2. Using any text editor to create the following two Notebook files, which contain unsafe dynamic function `FileNames[ ]`:

   ```
   Notebook[{Cell[BoxData[DynamicBox[ToBoxes[FileNames[],StandardForm],UpdateInterval:>0]],"Output"]}]
   ```

   ---

   ```
   Notebook[{Cell[BoxData[DynamicBox[ToBoxes[FileNames[],StandardForm],UpdateInterval:>0]],"Output"]},DynamicUpdating->True]
   ```
3. Open them in *Mathematica*, we can see both of them being alerted.

   [image: forced DynamicUpdating notebook 2]

So in my opinion, it should be as safe as other method to use this `DynamicUpdating` option at the Notebook level.

**Note:** There IS a **potential unsafe issue** as described by [Jacob Akkerboom](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38692/drawing-an-arrow-pointing-at-the-enable-dynamics-button/38719?noredirect=1#comment116128_38719). That is, when there is an alarm bar as shown above, you can ignore it but just run some code with dynamic function (like as simple as `Dynamic[]`) to enable the dynamic-updating, which also cause the former forbiden dynamic Cell to work, which may contain harmful code!

Comment: Are you sure it works?

Comment: @Kuba I saved a nb with a cell `Cell[BoxData[DynamicBox[ToBoxes[Date[],StandardForm],ImageSizeCache->{249.,{2.,8.}},UpdateInterval:>0]],"Output"]` and with this option set to `True`, opened a fresh new MMA, disabled the dynamic updating from menubar, then I opened the nb, it works.

Comment: Strange, it does not work for me. Aren't testing that in safe directory? Maybe it's OS specific, I'm on Win7. But at the end, it would be strange if such simple soultion is walkaround for protection procedure.

Comment: @Kuba I'm using MMA 9 on win8. Maybe I can upload a same nb for your testing?

Comment: @Kuba And when you back please see my update :)

Comment: @Kuba I just tried a path on my USB disk, it works all the same. So either it's a win8 issue, or a MMA security problem.

Comment: Ok, I know what is the source of the confusion :) I though you claim it should work when one open such notebook. But this should be evaluated manually like Alexei's example. Sorry for chaos :)

Comment: @Kuba It DOES work when I open such notebook! At step 3, I created one using any text editor, then opened it in MMA, it WORKS!

Comment: I would love to see what others are observing because it is not working for me :)

Comment: @Kuba I just tested some filesystem functions, found that they will be warned and the dynamic will be disabled. But other than that, even complex Dynamic object faced no resistance.

Comment: I will try this tomorrow at university :)

Comment: @Kuba Just find some editor, put `Notebook[{Cell[BoxData[DynamicBox[ToBoxes[Date[],StandardForm],UpdateInterval:>0]],"Output"]},DynamicUpdating->True]` in an empty file and save it as xxx.nb :)

Comment: Silvia, on MacOSX MMA version 9.0.1 the following happens when I uncheck enable dynamic updating and make the new notebook using your code. First of all I see this changing date, so dynamic updating works. Secondly, if I go to the evaluation menu while the notebook that was generated is in the front/selected, I see that there is once again a check after "enable dynamic updating". If I switch to the old notebook that was in front/selected when I disabled dynamic updating and check the evaluation menu, there is no check after "enable dynamic updating".

Comment: But the same thing happens when I remove `DynamicUpdating -> True` from the notebook-generating-code (i.e. the dynamic updating in the new notebook works). My guess is that there is another option in play

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Thanks for checking! That is exactly what I saw. Also, try disable the global dynamic-updating in the Option Inspector > Global Options > Cell Options > Evaluation Options. And try removing `DynamicUpdating -> True` now. I think it's indeed *the* option.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Sorry my mistake. I meant *Global Preferences* in the drop-down menu. It's listed under `Options[Notebook]` :)

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Hmm.. I think it's `Infinity` by default. `Infinity` means the dynamic object will not refresh unless something in it explicitly changed. And I think `Dynamic[Date[]]` should NOT refresh by default. Have you changed anything else?

Comment: Ah Silvia thank you! I was getting worried :). `x=0; Dynamic[x++]` works as expected :). By the way I have found that `Options[$FrontEnd, DynamicUpdating]` changes the setting in the option inspector. I think this option sets the value of DynamicUpdating for new notebooks. It is not the same as the option from the evaluation menu, as `DynamicUpdating` affects whether `Button`s work or not, whereas the menu option from the evaluation menu does not. But I guess it does largely the same thing. So +1, I think this is the best answer. Maybe you can also mention that setting the option of a ...

Comment: ...Notebook will cause these options to get saved when save the notebook. That makes it more clear how to use your suggestion :). Maybe you can also address that there will probably still be a warning: "this notebook contains potentially unsafe dynamic content". I think that will not be an issue though, as even not clicking "Enable Dynamics" and evaluating any cell will cause the `Dynamic` cells to work (strangely and "unsafely").

Comment: Also we should probably clean up the comments, but first: @Kuba hello :), does this work for you now?

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Hi Jacob :) I had tough day, now just chillin... I'm sorry I'm not able to focus on this now. But I will try tomorrow, this is important for me as related to what I usually do with MMA. Havea good night :) and soon, good day to you Silvia :) p.s. do not delete comments, they may be educational

Comment: @Kuba no problem, take it easy, I hope you can relax after your tough day. I have deleted two of my comments already, but I expect that you will have 20.000 rep soon so that you can see them later ;). Good night!

Comment: @Kuba Take your life easy my friend. And please see my update :)

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Thanks Jacob! I didn't know the strange unsafe issue! I think it's pretty dangerous...

Comment: @Silvia thank you too :) ; I now see that my little Q&A is incomplete/wrongish, as I failed to see that it matters whether or not "potentially unsafe functions" like `FileNames` are present. Just to be on the safe side: You say: "Mathematica will always detect unsafe dynamic content and raise an alarm if there is any". Technically such a warning is not produced if the file is on a "TrustedPath". I like your modifications, you have my imaginary +2 :P

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Thanks for reminding the "TrustedPath"!

Answer (score 4):

How about a cell at the top of the notebook containing a message to click the button, which then deletes itself when dynamic updating is enabled:

```
DynamicWrapper[Style["Click the stupid button! \[UpArrow]", "Title"], 
SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Before, Notebook];
SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Next, Cell];
NotebookDelete[]]
```

Note that the input cell will eat itself as soon as you evaluate it. If you then close and save the notebook, then re-open it, you should find that the message disappears after the enable dynamics button is clicked.

Comment: +1 Clever! I think the notebook manipulating functions make the dynamic-updating in this nb always be disabled by default?